# How to use Actionmailer.Net.Standalone in a console application?

Tags: c#, web-applications, razor, console-application, actionmailer.net

Is is possible to use `Actionmailer.Net.Standalone` in a console application? I keep getting an error that:

> Could not find any CSHTML or VBHTML views named [CRD.html.cshtml] in the path [EmailTemplates].  Ensure that you specify the format in the file name (ie: CRD.html.cshtml.txt.cshtml or CRD.html.cshtml.html.cshtml)

### Code

```
    public class Mailer : RazorMailerBase
{
    public override string ViewPath
    {
        get { return "EmailTemplates"; }
    }

    public RazorEmailResult Processed(string f)
    {

        From = group;
        To.Add(user);
        Subject = "CRD Process Server has processed file: " + f;
        return Email("CRD.html.cshtml");
    }
}
```

[image]

Do I need to implement a `RazorViewEngine` somewhere since it isn't standard with a console application?

Comment: By the way, the fix to this problem is right clicking `CRD.html.cshtml`, clicking properties, and changing Copy to Output Directory to 'Output if newer'.

Comment: Also, use NuGet to `Install-Package ActionMailer.Standalone`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a open source project as a general templating engine called [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/)

> A templating engine built upon Microsoft's Razor parsing technology.
>   The RazorEngine allows you to use Razor syntax to build robust
>   templates.

Simply;

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Also available in NuGet;

> Install-Package RazorEngine

Comment: Since this solution doesn't gain anything (such as intellisense in Actionmailer) that is pretty much like `string.Format(...)`

Comment: This does not even remotely answer the question

Answer (score 2):

A little late but maybe it still helps:

Try to change

```
return Email("CRD.html.cshtml");
```

to

```
return Email("CRD");
```

The extensions are appenden automatically.

Comment: You have the correct usage, but ActionMailer utilizes an http context that I did not have in my project. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: The ActionMailer.Standalone is independend of any HttpContext or dependencies to ASP.NET. For me it worked in a Console Application. The only thing is that it depends on the RazorEngine nuget package, which itself depends on the Microsoft.AspNet.Razor package. But that shouldn't cause any trouble normally.